# Change all links' sources in a Word document - Misplacement of Ranges

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I work on this code to **change the sources of all linked Fields/Charts/... in Word templates** to the workbook it is launched from.

I had **usual fields** and **charts** (which are stored in `InlineShapes`), so I have 2 loops for every template.

---

These loops sometimes stays stuck with `For Each`, and keep looping on `Fields`/`InlineShapes` (and don't even increase index...) without stopping. (I added the `DoEvents` for that, and it seems to reduce the frequency of that happening... **if you have an explanation, it'll be very welcome!**)

And with `For i = ... to .Count`, now it works pretty much flawlessly, **except for `Pasted Excel Range` which are changed to a range of the same size, starting on `A1` each time, and on the active sheet of the workbook**.

---

To avoid problems with `InlineShapes`, I added a test to know if the `LinkFormat.SourceFullName` is accessible and therefore avoid an error that would stop the process :

```
Function GetSourceInfo(oShp As InlineShape) As Boolean
Dim test As Variant
    On Error GoTo Error_GetSourceInfo
    test = oShp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
    GetSourceInfo = True
    Exit Function
Error_GetSourceInfo:
   GetSourceInfo = False
End Function
```

---

I noted 2 types of linked `InlineShapes` in my templates :

## Charts

Pasted as `Microsoft Office Graphic Object` :
`.hasChart` = -1
`.Type` = 12
`.LinkFormat.Type` = 8

## Ranges

Pasted as `Picture (Windows Metafile)` :
`.hasChart` = 0
`.Type` = 2
`.LinkFormat.Type` = 0

Here is my loop for `InlineShapes` :

```
For i = 1 To isCt
    If Not GetSourceInfo(oDoc.InlineShapes(i)) Then GoTo nextshape
        oDoc.InlineShapes(i).LinkFormat.SourceFullName = NewLink
        DoEvents
nextshape:
Next i
```

### Question

As I only update the `.SourceFullName`, which only describe Path and File, I have no clue on why or how this affect the initially selected range...

Problem recap : **`Pasted Excel Range` which are changed to a range of the same size, starting on `A1` each time, and on the active sheet of the workbook**.

And any other inputs on how to update Word links will be appreciated!

---

As suggested in **Andrew Toomey**'s answer, I worked with HyperLinks but in each one of my templates, the collection is empty :

[image]

---

I've tried quite a lot of different combinations and here is what I cleaned :

```
Sub change_Templ_Args()

Dim oW As Word.Application, _
    oDoc As Word.Document, _
    aField As Field, _
    fCt As Integer, _
    isCt As Integer, _
    NewLink As String, _
    NewFile As String, _
    BasePath As String, _
    aSh As Word.Shape, _
    aIs As Word.InlineShape, _
    TotalType As String

On Error Resume Next
Set oW = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set oW = CreateObject("Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
oW.Visible = True

NewLink = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

BasePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\_Templates\"
NewFile = Dir(BasePath & "*.docx")

Do While NewFile <> vbNullString
    Set oDoc = oW.Documents.Open(BasePath & NewFile)
    fCt = oDoc.Fields.Count
    isCt = oDoc.InlineShapes.Count
    MsgBox NewFile & Chr(13) & "Fields : " & oDoc.Fields.Count & Chr(13) & "Inline Shapes : " & isCt

    For i = 1 to fCt 
        With oDoc.Fields(i)
            '.LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = False
            'DoEvents
            .LinkFormat.SourceFullName = NewLink
            '.Code.Text = Replace(.Code.Text, Replace(.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, "\", "\\"), Replace(NewLink, "\", "\\"))
        End With
    Next i

    For i = 1 To isCt
        If Not GetSourceInfo(oDoc.InlineShapes(i)) Then GoTo nextshape
            With oDoc.InlineShapes(i)
                .LinkFormat.SourceFullName = NewLink
                DoEvents
                'MsgBox .LinkFormat.SourceFullName & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & _
                        "Type | LF : " & .LinkFormat.Type & Chr(13) & _
                        "Type | IS : " & .Type & Chr(13) & _
                        "hasChart : " & .HasChart & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & _
                        Round((i / isCt) * 100, 0) & " %" 
            End With
nextshape:
    Next i

    MsgBox oDoc.Name & " is now linked with this workbook!"
    oDoc.Save
    oDoc.Close
    NewFile = Dir()
Loop
oW.Quit

Set oW = Nothing
Set oDoc = Nothing

MsgBox "All changes done.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "End proc"

End Sub
```

Comment: You are running this from excel, the workbook you want all the docs to source from? Then opening the docs, looking for linked objects and replacing the reference with the WB you called the macro from?

Comment: @Raystafarian : Exactly this!

Comment: I have tested to update linked range and it worsk fine for me. Importatnt is not to change objects inside of for-each-next loop but use just for-next loop. Only thing i have experienced is that the Excel Sheet in NewLink must have a Sheet-Name which corresponds with the new sheet name.

Comment: @dee : Thx for input, I don't know why this problem of ranges isn't reproducing... :/
I'll make the changes immediately for the `For Each` and indeed I forgot to specify that it must been the same file structure to update the links. (I'm working on different computers and the Path is always changing, that's why I need this)

Comment: Do you have a sample file(s) that I can play around with? It will save me time from re-creating those and this way `maybe (not promising you that)` I will be able to give you a direct solution. If yes, then you may share it via dropbox. Also you may want to replace the original data with dummy data if the data is sensitive.

Comment: I'm going to make dummies today and and a link in comments here, and I can understand that you don't have any guarantees about finding a solution, don't worry! It is just that I know you are one of the guys here that know an awful lot more than me in VBA! ;) @SiddharthRout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using the `hyperlinks` collection is the key to your solution - unless you have a specific reason not to.  Links from a Word document to an Excel workbook are external links so should all be listed in the `Hyperlinks` collection (regardless of whether they are text links or InlineShapes that are linked).

Here's my code that may be of some help. For simplicity I've hard coded the Word document since that's not an issue for you:

```
Sub change_Templ_Args()
    WbkFullname = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    'Alternatively...
    'WbkFullname = "C:\temp\myworkbook.xlsx"
    'Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=WbkFullname

    'Get Document filename string
    MyWordDoc = "C\Temp\mysample.docx"

    Set oW = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oW.Documents.Open Filename:=MyWordDoc 
    Set oDoc = oW.ActiveDocument

    'Reset Hyperlinks
    For Each HypLnk In oDoc.Hyperlinks
        HypLnk.Address = WbkFullname
    Next

End Sub
```

If you really need to use `Fields` and `InlineShapes` try this code.  I've used variants in For loop and added a check for `wdLinkTypeReference` for fields that are Table of Contents or Cross Reference fields - these links are internal to the document.

```
'Reset links to InlineShapes
For Each InShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    If Not InShp.LinkFormat Is Nothing Then
        InShp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = WbkFullname
    End If
    If InShp.Hyperlink.Address <> "" Then
        InShp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = WbkFullname
    End If
Next

'Reset links to fields
For Each Fld In ActiveDocument.Fields
    If Not Fld.LinkFormat Is Nothing Then
        If Fld.LinkFormat.Type <> wdLinkTypeReference Then 
            Fld.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = WbkFullname
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thx for insights, but Hyperlink's collections are empty in my templates, though other are not... I hoped it was the thing that I missed, but nope. And about the other part, I keep getting the **error 5825** `Object has been deleted` on `InShp.Hyperlink.Address` and **error 6083** `Objects in this document contain links to files that cannot be found. The linked information will not be updated.` on `Fld.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = WbkFullname`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not all Fields/Shapes are linked and the original insert of the field/shape resulted in not all properties being created on the object.

To advance your code and find out in more detail what is the matter with the objects, try to ignore and report errors. Use watches to inspect the objects.

For example:

```
On Error Goto fieldError
For Each aField In oDoc.Fields
    With aField
        .LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = False
        DoEvents
        .LinkFormat.SourceFullName = NewLink
        .Code.Text = Replace(.Code.Text, Replace(.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, "\", "\\"), Replace(NewLink, "\", "\\"))
        Goto fieldContinue
      fieldError:
        MsgBox "error: <your info to report / breakpoint on this line>"
      fieldContinue:
    End With
Next aField
```

P.s.: what is the purpose of `DoEvents`? That will process external events (Windows messages).

Comment: Thx for input. DoEvents was an attempt to avoid being stuck in loop, it worked 90% of times now... Don't have a clue why though...
For error handling, I tried some of my own and spec with watches my elements (fields are ok, it's `InlineShapes` that are driving me nuts), I'm gonna edit question as I found a partial solution to my issue.