# Macro to update all fields in a word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have built - over the years - a vba macro that is supposed to update all fields in a word document.

I invoke this macro before releasing the document for review to ensure all headers and footers etc are correct.

Currently - it look like this:

```
Sub UpdateAllFields()
'
' UpdateAllFields Macro
'
'
    Dim doc As Document ' Pointer to Active Document
    Dim wnd As Window ' Pointer to Document's Window
    Dim lngMain As Long ' Main Pane Type Holder
    Dim lngSplit As Long ' Split Type Holder
    Dim lngActPane As Long ' ActivePane Number
    Dim rngStory As Range ' Range Objwct for Looping through Stories
    Dim TOC As TableOfContents ' Table of Contents Object
    Dim TOA As TableOfAuthorities 'Table of Authorities Object
    Dim TOF As TableOfFigures 'Table of Figures Object
    Dim shp As Shape

    ' Set Objects
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set wnd = doc.ActiveWindow

    ' get Active Pane Number
    lngActPane = wnd.ActivePane.Index

    ' Hold View Type of Main pane
    lngMain = wnd.Panes(1).View.Type

    ' Hold SplitSpecial
    lngSplit = wnd.View.SplitSpecial

    ' Get Rid of any split
    wnd.View.SplitSpecial = wdPaneNone

    ' Set View to Normal
    wnd.View.Type = wdNormalView

    ' Loop through each story in doc to update
    For Each rngStory In doc.StoryRanges
        If rngStory.StoryType = wdCommentsStory Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
            ' Update fields
            rngStory.Fields.Update
            Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
        Else
           ' Update fields
           rngStory.Fields.Update
            If rngStory.StoryType <> wdMainTextStory Then
                While Not (rngStory.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
                    Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
                    rngStory.Fields.Update
                Wend
            End If
        End If
    Next

    For Each shp In doc.Shapes
      If shp.Type <> msoPicture Then
        With shp.TextFrame
            If .HasText Then
                shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Fields.Update
            End If
        End With
      End If
    Next

    ' Loop through TOC and update
    For Each TOC In doc.TablesOfContents
        TOC.Update
    Next

    ' Loop through TOA and update
    For Each TOA In doc.TablesOfAuthorities
        TOA.Update
    Next

    ' Loop through TOF and update
    For Each TOF In doc.TablesOfFigures
        TOF.Update
    Next

    ' Header and footer too.
    UpdateHeader
    UpdateFooter
    
    ' Return Split to original state
    wnd.View.SplitSpecial = lngSplit

    ' Return main pane to original state
    wnd.Panes(1).View.Type = lngMain

    ' Active proper pane
    wnd.Panes(lngActPane).Activate

    ' Close and release all pointers
    Set wnd = Nothing
    Set doc = Nothing

End Sub

Sub UpdateFooter()
    Dim i As Integer
     
     'exit if no document is open
    If Documents.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     
     'Get page count
    i = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(14)
     
    If i >= 1 Then 'Update fields in Footer
        For Each footer In ActiveDocument.Sections(ActiveDocument.Sections.Count).Footers()
         footer.Range.Fields.Update
        Next
    End If
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
 
 'Update only the fields in your footer like:
Sub UpdateHeader()
    Dim i As Integer
     
     'exit if no document is open
    If Documents.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     
     'Get page count
    i = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(14)
     
    If i >= 1 Then 'Update fields in Header
        For Each header In ActiveDocument.Sections(ActiveDocument.Sections.Count).Headers()
         header.Range.Fields.Update
        Next
    End If
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have noticed recently that it sometimes misses some sections of the document. Today it missed *First page footer -section 2-* (the document version was not updated).

I have built this macro over a number of years and several bouts of research but I am not proud of it so please suggest a complete replacement if there is now a clean way of doing it. I am using Word 2007.

To test, create a word document and add a custom field named `Version` and give it a value. Then use that field `{DOCPROPERTY Version \* MERGEFORMAT }` in as many places as you can. Headers, Footers, first-page, subsequent page etc. etc. Remember to make a multi-section document with different header/footers. Then change the property and invoke the macro. It currently does quite a good job, handling TOCs and TOAs an TOFs etc, it just seems to skip footers (sometimes) in a multi-section document for example.

### Edit

The challenging document that seems to cause the most problems is structured like this:

It has 3 sections.

1. Section 1 is for the title page and TOC so the first page of that section has no header/footer but does use the `Version` property on it. Subsequent pages have page numbering in roman numerals for the TOC.
2. Section 2 is for the body of the document and has headers and footers.
3. Section 3 is for the copyright blurb and this has a very strange header and a cut-down footer.

All footers contain the `Version` custom document property.

My code above seems to work in all cases except sometimes it misses first page footer of sections 2 and 3.

Comment: Why not update directly all the Fields within the Document with `ActiveDocument.Fields.Update`? Or directly from the application level `Application.Fields.Update`?Does it miss some of them too?

Comment: @R3uK - `ActiveDocument.Fields.Update` does almost nothing. `Application.Fields.Update` gives an error `Method or data member not found` on the `Fields` object.

Comment: Ok. And does you have anything else that is linked but might not be in Fields? Like Charts, ...? I never used the application level my self, I just found that `.Fields` are a children of the Application level...

Comment: @R3uK - Documents may have charts (but rarely) and if macro misses them I will be happy to dig out changes to deal with that. For now I would be happy with a fix to it missing *First page footer -section 2-*. If that makes it simpler too it would be a bonus.

Comment: For charts, I had to update the links in some templates for a reporting system, here is my question with some things that should help you for charts : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958172/change-all-links-sources-in-a-word-document-misplacement-of-ranges

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For years, the standard I've used for updating all fields (with the exception of TOC, etc. which are handled separately) in a document is the one the Word MVPs use and recommend, which I'll copy here. It comes from Greg Maxey's site: http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/word_fields.html. One thing it does that I don't see in your version is update any fields in Shapes (text boxes) in the header/footer.

```
Public Sub UpdateAllFields()
  Dim rngStory As Word.Range
  Dim lngJunk As Long
  Dim oShp As Shape
  lngJunk = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.StoryType
  For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    'Iterate through all linked stories
    Do
      On Error Resume Next
      rngStory.Fields.Update
      Select Case rngStory.StoryType
        Case 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
          If rngStory.ShapeRange.Count > 0 Then
            For Each oShp In rngStory.ShapeRange
              If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Fields.Update
              End If
            Next
          End If
        Case Else
          'Do Nothing
        End Select
        On Error GoTo 0
        'Get next linked story (if any)
        Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
      Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Works for me - much tidier too.

Comment: Oops! Missed one! See my edit - misses footer of section 3.

Comment: First thing to do is determine whether only this document (or only documents from the same template) are exhibiting the problem. Word documents can "go bad" and when they do it's almost always in the section breaks, meaning it affects headers/footers. There's no way any macro can work around that kind of problem. Standard trouble-shooting steps include 1) saving to another file format, closing, re-opening and saving back to the original format; 2) Copying the content section-by-section WITHOUT the section breaks or the last paragraph mark to a new document (recreating section info manually)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I suspect the fact that my posted addition [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33734800/823393) fixes the problem suggest it is just something being skipped by the loop, but as it is not consistent we may be working with a broken doc. I think for now I will take your neater loop, add my extra loop and use that.

Comment: What is the purpose of lngJunk? Seems like it could be removed from this subroutine unless retrieving ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.StoryType has some necessary side effect.

Comment: This does not work for fields contained in text boxes contained in the header / footer. Checked on Word 2016

Answer (score 4):

Some research and experimentation produced the following addition which seems to solve the additional problem of updating the headers/footers in a multi-section document.

Add the following dimensions to the earlier answer:

```
dim sctn as Word.Section
dim hdft as Word.HeaderFooter
```

And then, add to the earlier code

```
for each sctn in doc.Sections
  for each hdft in sctn.Headers
     hdft.Range.Fields.Update
   next
   for each hdft in sctn.Footers
     hdft.Range.Fields.Update
   next
next
```

However - I am still not happy with this code and would very much like to replace it with something less hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for these answers! I found the answers very good and learned some stuff about ms-word macros. I thought I'd make my own answer for consideration (and adding some more search engine keywords - my searches didn't bring me here immediately).

I took inspiration from the citations in the footnotes.

I had an issue where MS Word fields were not updating in Textbox (Shapes).

I was working on a 70 page word document (Word 2013) that contained a lot of figures/images/captions and cross-references. A common practice is for an image to be captioned e.g. Figure 7, so it can be easily cross-referenced. Often the caption is inside a textbox (shape) and grouped with/to the object its captioning.

So after some document editing and content reorganisation, the fields and cross-references can easily get out of logical sequence.

OK - no problem... pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>F9</kbd> to update the document fields should solve this?

Unfortunately that didn't work as expected to update fields in textboxes (shapes).

In this scenario where fields exist inside textboxes (shapes) <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>F9</kbd> only updated the fields ***not*** inside a textbox (shape).

One can assume this behaviour is because field updating (<kbd>F9</kbd>) works on selected text, and with the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>F9</kbd> approach only text outside of the textboxes (shapes) is selected, so the field update only applies outside of textboxes (shapes).

I'm surprised there is not a button on the ribbon to perform an "update all fields". There could even be a toggle option to prompt the user to **update all fields** when closing a document?

I checked Word's (2013) ribbon command list, and didn't find an Update All command.

[image]

## Solution UpdateAllFields()

[image: weeeeeee]

Like the code shared by @Cindy [here](/a/33762199), the following code should update fields wherever they are in the doc, header, footer, main doc, textbox, grouped and nested grouped textbox.

Create a macro with the following code, and then add to the Quick Access Toolbar (QAT)

1. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to open the Macros dialogue.
2. Enter a name for the Macro: `UpdateAllFields`
3. Press Create button
4. Paste the code:

```
Sub UpdateAllFields()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveDocument
        .Fields.Update
        .PrintPreview
        .ClosePrintPreview
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Finally add the Macro to the Quick Access Toolbar.

## Citations and inspirations:

The Q&A's in this post!

There is a related post on the Microsoft Community here: [Word 365 Fields not updating in Textbox [serious reproducible error]](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-365-fields-not-updating-in-textbox-serious/3455716a-4767-49d3-a4c3-0ecf4e94e77d). This suggests the issue is present in at least Word 2013 and Word 365.

There is a related post on Stack Overflow here: [Macro to update fields in shapes (textboxes) in footer in Microsoft Word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53913502/490487).

## Another example UpdateTextboxFields()

This was the first version of code I wrote as I was in research and solution mode. Its a recursive approach to update fields inside textboxes, even if they are inside a group, or nested group. **This doesn't update fields outside shapes.**

```
Public Sub UpdateTextboxFields()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveDocument
        Call IterateShapesCollection(.Shapes)
        .PrintPreview
        .ClosePrintPreview
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub IterateShapesCollection(col)
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In col
        ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype
        ' Ignore images and 
        If 1 = shp.Type Or 13 = shp.Type Then
            GoTo NextIteration
        End If
        
        'Debug.Print ("Name: " & shp.Name & ", Type: " & shp.Type)
        
        ' if the type is a group, recurse
        If 6 = shp.Type Then
            Call IterateShapesCollection(shp.GroupItems)
        Else
            Call UpdateShapeFields(shp)
        End If
        
NextIteration:
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateShapeFields(shp)
    With shp.TextFrame
        If .HasText Then
            .TextRange.Fields.Update
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

## Word display option: Update fields before printing

cite: Microsoft article [Some fields are updated while other fields are not](https://web.archive.org/web/20221129151921/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/some-fields-are-updated-while-other-fields-are-not-eb3ad53a-328b-a3b4-91c6-28a84001855f)

The concept behind this option/approach is: all document fields are updated when you open print preview.

It looks like this option in Word (tested in 2013) updates all fields with a caveat - see below - you may need to open and close print preview twice.

File → Options → Display → Print options section → Update fields before printing

[image]

## Caveat if the doc has cross-references to figures/captions

This caveat applies to the word **"Update fields before printing"** display option and the UpdateAllFields() macro.

**IF** the document contains cross-references to figures/captions (with numbers), and those figures/captions have changed sequence/place in the document...

You must update the fields twice, 1) to reflect the figures/captions update, and then 2) to update the cross-references.