# Macro to update all fields including header and footer

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using Word 2016 and have tried to use the Macro here: [Macro to update all fields in a word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33733113/macro-to-update-all-fields-in-a-word-document) to update all the fields in my document (including headers and footers). However, now all the cross-referenced page numbers are set to "1", but everything else works perfectly.

But, when I select "Print" and just go back, all my fields and page numbers update correctly, including headers and footers.

Does someone know what "default" macro Word itself runs when you select "Print", but only the updating part?

Answer (score 1):

This could be an issue with your particular document. Incorrect page numbers might indicate that your document needs pagination. You can enforce pagination using this code:

```
ActiveDocument.Repaginate
```

Comment: I have tried that, Dirk, but for some reason, as soon as I make any changes to my document, and update, the page numbers go back to 1. I created a new Doc, and got the same problem. I wonder if it has to do with the fact that some of the bookmarked text that I cross-reference to is also in a form field, which is selected to be not-editable and not-deletable.

Comment: I've inserted cross-references to bookmarks in form fields as page numbers. These are the page numbers that give me the problem. And it's getting stranger - I have changed all my fields so that now _Contents cannot be edited_ is unticked. So now, when I execute the macro, all my page numbers go back to 1. But when I select all and press F9, the correct page numbers appear. So, I included the _select all, update_ in my macro, and now the numbers still go back to 1. Even when I go to print preview, the page numbers go to 1. Only selecting all and updating gives me the correct values.