# How to Update {PAGE} Field Codes with MS Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, office-interop

I'm creating a document with Open XML C# and also added Field Codes. To refresh those field codes I'm now using MS Interop and Word 2016. Unfortunately my {PAGE} field codes are not being refreshed properly.

They are being refreshed once, but their result is then 2 (this is where my first {PAGE} field appears), for every {PAGE} field code and for every page.

*CTRL + A* and *F9* refreshes my field codes properly. However I need it to happen programmatically.

This here is my code so far:

```cs
    Application app = new Application();
    document = app.Documents.Open(filePath);

    foreach(Field field in document.Fields)
    {
        field.Update();
    }        

    document.Close();
    app.Quit();
```

I'm very happy if anyone can help!

Comment: I assume your page fields are in the header or footer?

Comment: No, they are in the main document part

Comment: [Call `Repaginate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928691/macro-to-update-all-fields-including-header-and-footer) before updating the fields.

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Macro to update all fields including header and footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928691/macro-to-update-all-fields-including-header-and-footer)