# VBA - Update Headers Fields to Word From Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I try to update headers fields in my word document after export datas from excel.

Here is what I am trying:

```
Dim wd As Word.Application 
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document 
Set wd = New Word.Application
Set wdDoc = wd.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template_rapportfusion.docx ")

[... my code for export data ...]

'Update fields
wdDoc.Fields.Update

'Save the document
wdDoc.SaveAs2 (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & QuestionSheet.Range("Nom_Organisme") & "-" & QuestionSheet.Range("Date").Value & ".docx")
   
'Close the document
 wdDoc.Close
 wd.Quit
```

But nothing happens on the update, my fields are linked on a bookmark who is updated whith my script.

Can somebody help me ?

Thank you very much, Lyrha.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33733113/macro-to-update-all-fields-in-a-word-document

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
With wdDoc
  'Update fields
  .Fields.Update
  .PrintPreview
  .ClosePrintPreview
  'Save the document
  .SaveAs2 (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & QuestionSheet.Range("Nom_Organisme") & "-" & QuestionSheet.Range("Date").Value & ".docx")
  'Close the document
  .Close False
End With
```