# Word VBA Document.ClosePrintPreview intermittently crashes with runtime error 4605

Tags: vba, ms-word, print-preview

I am experiencing intermittent runtime error when doing the following in Word 2007 VBA:

```
Doc.PrintPreview
Doc.ClosePrintPreview
```

Here Doc is a valid document that was successfully opened by the same VBA script (not by the user).

Basically, I need print preview to open (for the purposes of forcing the update of all the fields) and then close it right away. The problem is that in about 20% of cases ClosePrintPreview crashes with runtime error 4605, complaining that the document is **not** in print preview mode, as if previous PrintPreview method call never did its job.

I can't visually confirm whether the PrintPreview actually did its job because the whole thing happens in pretty busy and tight loop, so Word does not update anything on the screen (even though I never turned off Application.ScreenUpdating).

It happens when the script is processing large documents that have several thousands of fields (print preview takes time to be generated when called interactively). It does not happen on simple, small-size documents.

And the whole thing happens intermittently, so I really can't figure out what triggers it. In about 80% of cases the script runs just fine.

So, the question is whether it is PrintPreview that really fails (which is not good and would need to be addressed, because I call it for a reason) or is it just ClosePrintPreview that gets confused and I could safeguard it with something like

```
If Application.PrintPreview = True Then Doc.ClosePrintPreview
```

Has anyone seen anything similar?

Comment: Why use a Print Preview kludge when you could use _ActiveDocument.Fields.Update_?

Comment: Mainly because that single command does not actually update everything in the document, see this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33733113/macro-to-update-all-fields-in-a-word-document