# Using VBA to print current Word doc to pdf without saving or dialogs

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word, dialog

So I want to search a Word doc for broken cross-references. I know typically one would select all and then update fields and all the broken cross-references will be "Error! Reference source not found." The issue is that the documents I am dealing with are massive, full of tables and figures, and larded up with styles. More often than not Cntl-A will just end up hanging the document.

The work around I have found that consistently works is printing to PDF and discarding the PDF.

I'd like to automate this and preferably not actually saving the pdf nor showing any of the print dialog boxes. From the users standpoint they would click a button on a userform that would cause all the broken references in the active document to be exposed with the standard error text which can then be searched.

I am open to suggestions regarding something less kludgy than the print to pdf method but given the complexity of the underlying templates (which I have no control over), I can't much rely on elements of the documents themselves.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33762199/5211752

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to mark the broken cross-references to check out, right?

How about this:

```vb
Sub MarkInvalidCrossReferences()
    Dim ref
    Dim f As Field
    Dim d As Document, rng As Range
    Dim cln As New VBA.Collection, ur As UndoRecord
    Set ur = word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "MarkInvalidCrossReferences"
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    
    For Each rng In d.StoryRanges
        
        'd.Fields.Update 'More often than not Cntl-A will just end up hanging the document.
        For Each f In rng.Fields 'd.Fields
            f.Update
            If f.Result = "錯誤! 尚未定義書籤。" Then 'this is my traditional Chinese version
            'If f.Result = "Error! Reference source not found." Then ' yours will be this
                f.Select
                Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow 'mark
                
                Rem maybe you want to wait here for further OP
                
                Rem store in a collection to further Use
                cln.Add Selection.Range.Duplicate
                
            End If
        Next f
        
    Next rng
    ur.EndCustomRecord
End Sub
```

Cause I don't have so large document to test, if the issue is still, then we'll try to in your pdf way.

> The issue is that the documents I am dealing with are massive, full of tables and figures, and larded up with styles. More often than not Cntl-A will just end up hanging the document.